# TextBox Text Management

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, textbox, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application where I'm trying to create a "diagnostics panel" that's very similar to the "Output Window" in Visual Studio 2010. It simply contains a text box where all types of output are collected and appended in the text box using the `.AppendText()` method.

We have a couple of customers who leave this diagnostics panel up all the time and never clear it. As a result, a very large amount of text gets displayed as new output continues to come in...

The WPF TextBox has a MaxLength property which I leave set to 0. According to the MSDN documentation, "When this property is set to 0, the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is limited only by available memory."

For the customers that leave this panel up, I hate to just let the text and memory grow uncontrolled... I think this may eventually cause the application to hang up...

I am curious if there's a good way to mange this... I want to keep a certain number of lines displayed in the text box and discard the oldest as new lines come in...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a listbox with each sentence getting its own textblock?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. What would a ListBox get me? I'm interested in your response. I'm just not sure what the advantage would be.

Comment: A TextBox should really just be used for manual text entry.

Comment: @John Russell http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/98090161-0abf-4799-bbcb-852dcc0f0608

Comment: @iterationx, Thanks for the response. I admit I was a little skeptical at first until I saw that using an ItemsControl would give you the Virtualization benefits. Works much better!

Comment: @iterationx, Can you post your comments as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a listbox with each sentence getting its own textblock - so you can get virtualization?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/98090161-0abf-4799-bbcb-852dcc0f0608

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `DispatcherTimer` in your code behind. With this you,  you can set it to `Tick` every 10 minutes (or whatever time period you want). And in the Tick event handler method, you can take the text in your textbox, throw away the all but the amount of text you want to save and then set the that text back to the textbox.

You could also save the text to a log text file. You'd have to figure out what to append to the text file so you won't write the same text to it multiple times. This depends on what exactly your needs are.

[DispatcherTimer documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

Like Xaisoft said, you shouldn't use a `TextBox` for this, probably a `TextBlock` instead. You might have to put that inside a `ScrollViewer`, I don't remember.

Comment: But, what if the users want to save all the text.

Comment: Instead of throwing it away you could write it to a log text file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you handle it:

1. Write the log info to a text file
2. Write the log info to your text box (although I don't like textboxes, it should be okay.)
3. When writing to the text box, only display the last maybe 20 or so (play with this) lines.  Everything else should "roll off"

If your users really want to save everything, no biggie, it already is saved to that file.

Upon each execution of the app, or at some appropriate interval, roll your logging to a new file.